# Como realizar update em many to many relation usando o connect do prisma?

Tags: postgresql, typescript, prisma

Possuo uma [implicit many to many relation](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations/many-to-many-relations#implicit-many-to-many-relations) com os models:

```js
model User {
    id          Int         @id @default(autoincrement())
    username    String      @unique
    password    String
    rooms       Room[]

    @@map("users")
}

model Room {
    id          Int         @id @default(autoincrement())
    name        String  
    users       User[]

    @@map("rooms")
}
```

Um usuário `User` pode querer entrar em diferentes salas `Room`, que já existam e já possuam outros usuários. Então a ideia é procurar todas as `rooms` nas quais o `user` quer entrar e adicioná-lo àquela `room`. Como vou atualizar várias entradas, optei pelo `updateMany()` em par com o [connect API](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#connect):

```js
export async function insertUserIntoRooms(insertionData) {
    const { user, rooms } = insertionData;

    const alteredRooms = await client.room.updateMany({
        where: {
            OR: rooms.map(room => ({ id: room.id }))
        },
        data: {
            users: {
                connect: { id: user.id },
            }
        }
    })

    return alteredRooms;
}
```

Acontece que o `updateMany()` não me dá acesso ao campo `users`, só aos campos de dados primitivos. Disparando o erro:

> ```
> Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'users' does not exist in type '(Without<RoomUpdateManyMutationInput, RoomUncheckedUpdateManyInput> & RoomUncheckedUpdateManyInput) | (Without<...> & RoomUpdateManyMutationInput)'.
> ```

Como fazer essa operação então?

Answer (score 0):

Seguindo o caso de uso para sua aplicação, creio que o esquema não seja melhor dessa forma, caso deseje que um usuário tenha a capacidade de criar uma sala e outros usuários possam participar dessa sala, é necessário criar mais uma tabela para que assim possa armazenar onde diferentes usuário estão na mesma sala.

Segue o esquema abaixo:

```
model User {
    id          Int         @id @default(autoincrement())
    username    String      @unique
    password    String

    @@map("users")
}

model Room {
    id          Int         @id @default(autoincrement())
    name        String  

    @@map("rooms")
}

model UserRoom {
    id          Int         @id @default(autoincrement())
    idUser      @db.Int
    user        User @relation(fields: [idUser], references: [id])
    idRoom      @db.Int
    room        Room @relation(fields: [idRoom], references: [id])

    @@map("user_room")
}
```

Você poderá usar um `map` para criar os objetos antes de utilizar o `createMany` em `UserRoom`, definindo assim em qual sala os usuários vão estar.

O link a frente explica um pouco mais sobre os esquemas de relacionamento:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296846/how-to-implement-one-to-one-one-to-many-and-many-to-many-relationships-while-de)

Comment: Oi André! Acredito que nós fizemos a mesma coisa. Como falei na questão, eu fiz uma [implicit many to many relation](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations/many-to-many-relations#implicit-many-to-many-relations), enquanto no seu exemplo temos uma [explicit many to many](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations/many-to-many-relations#explicit-many-to-many-relations).
Nas duas estratégias o prisma cria a tabela intermediária, a diferença é só que eu não declarei ela explicitamente, como você fez, pois o prisma cuida disso pra mim.

Comment: Outra nuance é que, declarando ela implicitamente, eu não posso fazer queries nessa tabela intermediária, enquanto se tivesse declarado explicitamente, poderia. Pra reforçar, parafraseio a documentação: `Implicit many-to-many relations define relation fields as lists on both sides of the relation. Although the relation table exists in the underlying database, it is managed by Prisma and does not manifest in the Prisma schema. `